# Equation of a curve in $R^3$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a curve $\gamma$ defined ad the intersection between $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and $x-2z=3$.I want prove that exists $r>0$ such that the curve is in $B(0,r)$, then to find points of min and max distance from the origin.
For the first question I proved that the curve is locally the graph of a function, but what about the second question?

Answer (score 0):

*Locally being the graph of a function* does not imply *being bounded*, which is what you want to prove in the first point. Anyway, any point $(x,y,z)$ belonging to the intersection between $z^2=x^2+y^2$ (i.e. a cone) and $x-2z=3$ (i.e. a plane) fulfills $z^2=(3+2z)^2+y^2$, hence $|z|\leq 3$ and $x^2+y^2\leq 9$, from which the bounded-ness of such intersection immediately follows.

For the second point, you may notice that the squared distance from the origin is $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2z^2$, so you just have to minimize/maximize $z^2$ over $\gamma$, pretty simple.

Comment: i don't understand why |z|<3

Comment: @GiuliaB.: if $|z|>3$, there is no way $z^2=(3+2z)^2+y^2$ may hold. So $|z|$ is bounded and $|x|,|y|$ are bounded as well, giving that your curve is bounded.

Comment: Can I found r of the $B(0,r)$?

Comment: @GiuliaB.: you do it in the second part. The point with the greatest distance from the origin gives $r$.